# How to validate AWS Cognito JWT in .NET Core Web API using .AddJwtBearer()

Tags: .net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito, asp.net-core-webapi, jwk

I was having some trouble figuring out how to go about validating a JWT given to the client by AWS Cognito inside my .NET Core Web API.

Not only could I not figure out what the variables for `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters` were supposed to be, but once I finally did, I didn't know how to retrieve the JWT key set from `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{pool ID}/.well-known/jwks.json`

Finally, though a lot of random Googling and trial and error, I found a (seemingly-not-very-efficient solution) solution. However, I spent way too much time doing it. Citing that, plus the fact that AWS documentation on the subject is severely lacking, I decided to post this Q&A to help others find this solution more easily in the future.

If there's a better way to do this, somebody *please* tell me because I have yet to find a way to do this besides my answer listed below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The answer lies primarily in correctly defining the `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeyResolver` (parameters, etc. seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.issuersigningkeyresolver?view=azure-dotnet).

This is what tells .NET Core what to verify the JWT sent against. One must also tell it where to find the list of keys. One cannot necessarily hard-code the key set, as it is often rotated by AWS.

One way to do it would be to fetch and serialize the list from the URL inside the `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` method. The whole `.AddJwtBearer()` might look something like this:

**Startup.cs ConfigureServices() method:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (s, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                        {
                            // get JsonWebKeySet from AWS
                            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(parameters.ValidIssuer + "/.well-known/jwks.json");
                            // serialize the result
                            var keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWebKeySet>(json).Keys;
                            // cast the result to be the type expected by IssuerSigningKeyResolver
                            return (IEnumerable<SecurityKey>)keys;
                        },

                        ValidIssuer = "https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{pool ID}",
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidAudience = "{Cognito AppClientID}",
                        ValidateAudience = true
                    };
                });
```

If you use a JS library such as AWS Amplify, you can see parameters such as the `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience` in your browser's console by observing the result of `Auth.currentSession()`

A REST fetch request from a JS client to a .NET Core Web API utilizing the JWT Authentication achieved above as well as using the `[Authorize]` tag on your controller might look something like this:

**JS Client using @aws-amplify/auth node package:**

```
// get the current logged in user's info
Auth.currentSession().then((user) => {
fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/values',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      // get the user's JWT token given to it by AWS cognito 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
).then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(e => console.error(e))
})
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Amplify on client side has been changed a bit so for the token now we should use user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken :)

Comment: As in 2021 (core 3.1), `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWebKeySet>(json)` might not work - use this instead: `new JsonWebKeySet(json)`

Comment: This example creates a new WebClient and downloads the keys again for every authenticated request. You can instead set the metadata address on JwtBearerOptions and it will handle fetching the keys and caching for you.  For ex.,

`options.MetadataAddress = "https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<pool>/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Answer (score 10):

This has been easily the most difficult bit of code I've had to work with in the last year. "Authenticating JWT tokens from AWS Cognito in a .NET Web API app". AWS documentation still leaves much to be desired.

Here's what I used for a new **.NET 6** Web API solution (so Startup.cs is now contained within Program.cs. Adjust to fit your version of .NET if needed. Main difference vs .NET 5 and earlier is the `Services` object is accessed via a variable called `builder`, so anytime you see code like `services.SomeMethod...`, you can likely replace it with `builder.Services.SomeMethod...` to make it .NET 6-compatible):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = "https://cognito-idp.{aws region here}.amazonaws.com/{Cognito UserPoolId here}",
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidAudience = "{Cognito AppClientId here}",
            ValidateAudience = false
        };

        options.MetadataAddress = "https://cognito-idp.{aws region here}.amazonaws.com/{Cognito UserPoolId here}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    });
```

Note that I have `ValidateAudience` set to `false`. I was getting 401 Unauthorized responses from the .NET app otherwise. Someone else on SO has said they had to do this to get OAuth's Authentication/Authentication Code grant type to work. Evidently `ValidateAudience = true` will work just fine for implicit grant, however implicit grant is regarded as deprecated by most and you should try to avoid it if possible.

Also note that I am setting `options.MetadataAddress`. Per another SO user, this apparently allows for behind the scenes caching of the signing keys from AWS that they rotate from time to time.

I was led astray by some official AWS documentation (boo) that had me using `builder.Services.AddCognitoIdentity();` (`services.AddCognitoIdentity();` for .NET 5 and earlier). Apparently this is for "ASP.NET" apps where the backend serves up the frontend (e.g. Razor/Blazor). Or maybe it's deprecated, who knows. It is on AWS's website so it could very well be deprecated...

As for the Controllers, a simple `[Authorize]` attribute at the class level sufficed. No need to specify "Bearer" as the `AuthenticationScheme` in the `[Authorize]` attribute, or create middleware.

If you want to skip having to add another `using` to every controller as well as the `[Authorize]` attribute, and you want every endpoint in every controller to require a JWT, you can put this in Startup/Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Make sure that in Program.cs (Startup.cs for .NET 5 and earlier) `app.UseAuthentication` comes before `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Here are the `using`s in Program.cs/Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

Comment: Thank You! Saved me some serious headaches today!

Comment: After one day of testing and searching the internet I found the fix for `services.AddCognitoIdentity();`. This is not deprecated but the authentication scheme used by default is cookie. To override it you need to add `AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })`. But I have to agree with the comment about AWS docs

Comment: Right on. Is there a reason one would want to use the code in my answer over `AddCognitoIdentity()` / vice-versa?

Comment: Using `AddCognitoIdentity()` contains the boilerplate needed for using Asp.Net Identity. That means that you can use `CognitoUserManager<CognitoUser>` which again has some prebuilt functions to manipulate the users that will save you some time

Comment: Also ValidateAudiance is not working because you are using the `AccessToken` which does not contain the `aud` claim. In order to validate the audiance you need to use the `IdToken`.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) _The purpose of the access token is to authorize API operations in the context of the user in the user pool. For example, you can use the access token to grant your user access to add, change, or delete user attributes_ vs _The ID token can also be used to authenticate users to your resource servers or server applications. You can also use an ID token outside of the application with your web API operations_

Answer (score 8):

The provided answer here is only required if you need more fine grained control over validation.

Otherwise the following code is sufficient to validate jwt.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "{yourAuthorizationServerAddress}";
    options.Audience = "{yourAudience}";
});
```

Okta have a good article on this. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide

> When the JwtBearer middleware handles a request for the first time, it
>   tries to retrieve some metadata from the authorization server (also
>   called an authority or issuer). This metadata, or discovery document
>   in OpenID Connect terminology, contains the public keys and other
>   details needed to validate tokens. (Curious what the metadata looks like? Here’s an example discovery document.)
>
> If the JwtBearer middleware finds this metadata document, it
>   configures itself automatically. Pretty nifty!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was unable to the method you described to work *specifically with AWS Cognito and Amplify* when I did this back in 2018. I had, however, used JWT with my own authentication and user management implementation successfully many times. However, if this works now, that's great news!

Comment: Would this handle the rotation of key-set?