# AWS Cognito : Need to validate AWS cognito JWT bearer token in every request in Azure functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-functions, amazon-cognito

I am using `Azure functions` as backend. I want to authenticate every request that whether it is having JWT token or not.

I tried to implementing it by using `AddAuthentication()`. but It doesn't seem to work in azure functions.

I tried this link this as well [Validate AWS cognito in .net core api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244446/how-to-validate-aws-cognito-jwt-in-net-core-web-api-using-addjwtbearer)

After implementing the above link I got an error

> no authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'bearer' in
>   azure functions

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the ValidateToken method of the JwtSecurityTokenHandler .

Docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451155(v=vs.114).aspx.